# How do I replace unwanted commas in a comma delimited file in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, railo, lucee

I am loading a CSV, and trying to insert the contents in MySQL. One of the fields has commas in it, so for example:

```
 "Jane Doe","Boston","None","Yes","No"
 "John Doe","New York","No garlic, onions, or nuts","Yes","No"
 "Mary Doe","New York","None","Yes","No"
```

I start by reading in the file:

```
<cffile action="read"file="/var/www/html/temp.csv" variable="datacsv">
```

Then I start a loop:

```
<cfloop index="index" list="#datacsv#" delimiters="#chr(13)#,#chr(10)#">
    <cfset item1 = Replace(listgetAt(index,1), """", "", "ALL")> #item1#<br>
    <cfset item2 = Replace(listgetAt(index,2), """", "", "ALL")> #item2#<br>
    <cfset item3 = Replace(listgetAt(index,3), """", "", "ALL")> #item3#<br>
    <cfset item4 = Replace(listgetAt(index,4), """", "", "ALL")> #item4#<br>
    <cfset item5 = Replace(listgetAt(index,5), """", "", "ALL")> #item5#<br>
</cfloop>
```

My problem here is that in the second item (John Doe), those commas in the 3rd field are getting parsed out as new fields.  So I either need to figure out what I am missing that is causing that, OR to strip the commas in any field and replace them with a different character.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? Spreadsheet or database?

Comment: I see that you have smart quotes in there. Will your string have smart quotes or is this just an example?

Comment: Database, and the smart quotes are just example.  All I am worried about are those commas between the quotes.

Comment: Any reason you cannot use MySQL's [bulk loading tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)? It should handle embedded commas and is generally much faster than inserting one row at a time.

Comment: Because I need to perform a bunch of logic before I actually insert into MySQL

Comment: What kind of logic? Unless it is extremely complex, it can usually be handled with SQL. 1) MySQL supports some manipulation of data during the insert using `SET`. 2) You can also insert data into temp tables first. Then perform validation/scrubbing on the temp table, and insert the data into the target table when finished - all using set based operations.

Comment: I am using an example for something that in the actual case has 54 fields.  Each field in each row needs to be checked against multiple tables.  In some cases a new row will need to be inserted in a table with SOME of the data, in others a new row in a different table will need to be inserted with SOME of the data.  In other cases SOME of those field will need to be updates, and in others ignored.  While this can surely be done in SQL, We are porting from an old system to a new one.  I know how to do all the logic in CFML (and have already done most of it).

Comment: Just one note: "I know how to do all the logic in CFML" shouldn't mean that's the best way to do it, even if most of it has already been done. Sometimes it's well worth your time and effort to learn a new method. If this is large data, you could be throwing a huge bottleneck in your way by validating on the app side instead of the SQL side.

Comment: RE: *Each field in each row needs to be checked against multiple tables* @mck - That is the strength of using staging tables. Data is imported into staging tables, and validation/insert/update/deletes are done via set based operations, which generally scale better and offer greater control of the overall batch of data.  I have used that approach in many applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this regex to replace the embedded commas with dashes:

```
<cfscript>

    // CSV content
    csvContent = '"John Doe","New York","No garlic, onions, or nuts","Yes","No"';

    // Replace all comma in between with dash
    writeOutput(
        csvContent.replaceAll(
            ',(?!")|(?<!"),(?=[^"]*?"(?:,|\r?\n|\r|$))', '-'
        )
    );
</cfscript>
```

Here is the [`GIST`](http://trycf.com/gist/7af6c56585303bf2946525d736a5e989/acf2016?theme=monokai).

**Edit:**

> This works, but it is also stripping out any CR/LF in there. As I loop through my items, I am doing: `<cfloop index="index" list="#csvContent#" delimiters="#chr(13)#,#chr(10)#">`

You can simply use CR/LF( `chr(13)chr(10)` ) as the delimiter.
Here is an example:

```
<!--- CSV content --->
<cfset csvContent = '"John Doe","New York","No garlic, onions, or nuts","Yes","No"'>

<!--- Replace all comma in between with dash --->
<cfset newCsvContent = csvContent.replaceAll(
    ',(?!")|(?<!"),(?=[^"]*?"(?:,|\r?\n|\r|$))', '-'
)>

<!--- Process records --->
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop list="#newCsvContent#" index="csvRow" delimiters="#chr(13)##chr(10)#">
        Column 1: #replace( csvRow.listGetAt( 1 ), """", "", "ALL")#<br>
        Column 2: #replace( csvRow.listGetAt( 2 ), """", "", "ALL")#<br>
        Column 3: #replace( csvRow.listGetAt( 3 ), """", "", "ALL")#<br>
        Column 4: #replace( csvRow.listGetAt( 4 ), """", "", "ALL")#<br>
        Column 5: #replace( csvRow.listGetAt( 5 ), """", "", "ALL")#<br>
        <br>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: This works, but it is also stripping out any CR/LF in there.  As I loop through my items, I am doing:  <cfloop index="index" list="#csvContent#" delimiters="#chr(13)#,#chr(10)#">

Comment: OK, I just reformatted the entire question to make the problem more clear.  Hope someone can help.  Thanks

Comment: @mck Check http://trycf.com/gist/3ec78b43618e3fbbbbf32508bef280ef/acf2016?theme=monokai

Answer (score 2):

Use `<cfhttp>` instead of `<cffile>` to read the file.  The name attribute gives you a query attribute.  [This document](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html) states that the default value of the textQualifier is a double quote, but I would specify it anyway.

Comment: Just tried it, and while the DUMP parses everything perfectly, it is still breaking in the loop.  Is this something wrong in Replace(listgetAt(index... ?

Comment: RE: *This works, but it is also stripping out any CR/LF in there* mck - @Beginner's example worked fine for me.  Can you please create a runnable gist that reproduces that issue? http://trycf.com/gist/0510cfa439898f98b3d9b833d7c77bcd/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: Here, have a look here and you will see it breaks at "No Garlic"  where it should say "No garlic, onions, or nuts" https://trycf.com/gist/e0c414ef9b5ef90706ee8e136a67ef06/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: @mck - Um... you did not implement the replaceAll code they suggested in the [last example](http://trycf.com/gist/3ec78b43618e3fbbbbf32508bef280ef/acf2016?theme=monokai) :) It works fine once you do that.

Comment: @Leigh That did it... Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank @Beginner. It was their code ;-) (Nothing against the answer, but personally I prefer bulk loading tools over individual inserts, much faster). Anyway, since it worked as advertised, I voted to "undelete" their answer. Not sure why it was down voted in the first place ...